# React + Spring Boot 1.5 + Jboss 6.4 + Realm + AD

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, active-directory

I need to build a solution with must to do this:

A react.js front-end application is my login page with user and password, so I need to get this two information and send to my back-end and authenticate this user and password in my realm based on Active Directory.

Someone could help me in this question?

-------------------EDITED-------------------------

I've tried this:

In my Jboss domain.xml file I've put:

```
<security-domain name="LdapSecurityDomain" cache-type="default">
<authentication>
    <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
        <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
        <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://AdAddress"/>
        <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
        <module-option name="bindDN" value="CN=DEV,OU=Service,OU=Accounts,OU=SAO,DC=am,DC=company,DC=com"/>
        <module-option name="bindCredential" value="DevPassword"/>
        <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="OU=Users,DC=yourCompany,DC=biz"/>
        <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(uid={0})"/>
        <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(member={1})"/>
        <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="CN=DEV,OU=Service,OU=Accounts,OU=SAO,DC=am,DC=company,DC=com"/>
        <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="cn"/>
        <module-option name="roleNameAttributeID" value="cn"/>
        <module-option name="roleRecursion" value="0"/>
        <module-option name="throwValidateError" value="true"/>
        <module-option name="java.naming.referral" value="follow"/>
        <module-option name="searchScope" value="SUBTREE_SCOPE"/>
        <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="unauthenticated"/>
        <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="false"/>
    </login-module>
</authentication>
```

And in my Jboss host.xml file I've put:

```
<outbound-connections>
    <ldap name="ldap_connection" url="ldap://AdAddress" search-dn="CN=DEV,OU=Service,OU=Accounts,OU=SAO,DC=am,DC=company,DC=com" search-credential="DevPassword" />
</outbound-connections>
```

So, I don't know, how to validate the user and password in this case, I'am trying to search something to help me in this case, but I find only Java to AD solutions without Jboss realm.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I've just edited my question, with I've tryied.